# Finding contour integral result using residue theorem

Tags: residue-calculus

I was wondering what the best way to solve this would be. I was using the cauchy integral residue formula which revolved around taking 2 derivatives since the poles are at +/- i and are of order 3. Quickly realized that taking double derivatives are pretty cumbersome. Is there a better way to solve it?

0<a=1

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{(z^{a-1})}{(z^2+1)^3}dz$

$I=\int_{C}\frac{(z^{a-1})}{(z^2+1)^3}dz$

[Cauchy integral residue integral formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A58GC.png)

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/why-image-cannot-be-used-for-explaining-my-maths-problem/34123#34123) about relying on images for essential parts of your question.

Comment: There is but please note you cannot directly apply the contour integration if $a$ is not an integer since the integrand won’t be meromorphic

Comment: @FShrike, forgot to include that 0<a<=1 which I assume that a doesn't have to be an integer

Answer (score 0):

First make the substitution $z= e^{2u}$ to cast the integrand into the form $\frac{ e^{\beta u} \ du}{ \cosh^3 u}$  where $\beta$ is real.

Then note that in terms of the complex variable  $w=u+iv$
$\cosh w = \cos (iw)$ is periodic with period $2\pi$ in $v$. This allows you to create a closed loop contour in the $w$ plane comprising  two parallel horizontal lines. The loop  encloses one singularity at $w= i\pi/2$.  Thus you are reduced to computing a single residue, at that triple pole.

To find the residue at the triple pole you need to find a Laurent expansion. You can exploit the trig identity $\cos (\pi/2+ \zeta)= -\sin \zeta =- \zeta+ \ldots$ and cube this to determine the Laurent expansion of the integrand there.

Note that the two vertical segments in your contour are harmless if the denominator grows much faster than the numerator. This will be true for a restricted range of $\beta $ values.